# MYSQL: Setting column value based on count grouped by other column

Tags: mysql

I have the table, which has following Columns:

```
 SchoolName              ClassSize
 ----------              ---------
    A                        NULL
    A                        NULL
    A                        NULL
    B                        NULL
    B                        NULL
```

I want to set values in ClassSize column based on the count of School names, like:

```
SchoolName                ClassSize
----------                ---------
    A                         3
    A                         3
    A                         3
    B                         2
    B                         2
```

Please let me know how to do it.

I am doing something like this:

```
update table as set ClassSize = (select count(SchoolName) from table group by SchoolName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a join of the table with the query that returns the counters:

```
update tablename t 
inner join (
  select schoolname, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by schoolname
) g on g.schoolname = t.schoolname
set t.ClassSize = g.counter;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5t7N3Vx8FSQmwUJgKLqjfK/1).
Results:

```
| SchoolName | ClassSize |
| ---------- | --------- |
| A          | 3         |
| A          | 3         |
| A          | 3         |
| B          | 2         |
| B          | 2         |
```

Comment: Now I want to calculate the percentile of ClassSize column. I am using
`select  f.ClassSize, round(100.0 * (select count(*) from tableName as f2 where f2.ClassSize <= f.ClassSize) / totals.classCount, 1) as percentile from tableName f cross join ( select count(*) as classCount from tableName ) as totals order by percentile desc;` but it doesn't return anything.  Can you please help?

Comment: What is your expected result, based on the values in the query in this answer?

Comment: Actually I have same ClassSize column with around 1 million records, but for now yes based on the values in the answer.

Comment: So what is your expected output?

Comment: I don't know, whatever is percentile of ClassSize. :)

Comment: Percentile of what? Of the total of all class sizes or of the total of each class size? There are 5 rows in this query. The 1st class size is 3. What will be the percentile of this row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201450/discussion-between-pardeep-kumar-and-forpas).